# jquery append to add li to ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to maintain a list of `<li>`'s for every selection made using jquery selectable

Here is my basic template for the HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="contentreplace"></div>
    <div class="buildoptions"><?=$buildoptions?></div>
</div>
```

`$buildoptions` is :

```
<p id="feedback">
    <span>You've selected:</span> 
<div id="select-result"><ul class='ul-depend'>Nothing Selected</ul></div>
</p>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".selectable" ).selectable({
  stop: function() {
    var html2 = "<div class='steps'> Select the dependant Field </div>";
    $('#select-result').empty().append(html2);

    var html = "";
    $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
        var ecid = $(this).data('ecid');
        var field = $(this).data('field');
        html = "<li class='depend' data-field='"+field+"' data-ecid='"+ ecid+"'>"+ecid+" - "+field+"</li>";
        $("#select-result ul.ul-depend").append(html)
    });

  }
});
});
```

Here is selectable html:

```
    <span class="ecdataset"><?=$stuff[0]['dataset']?></span>    
    <span class="ecvisit"><?=$stuff[0]['visit']?></span>
<ol class="selectable">
<?php
foreach ($stuff as $variable)
{?>
<li class="ui-widget-content" data-field="<?=$variable['field']?>" data-ecid="<?=$variable['ecspecs_id']?>">
    <textarea ><?=$variable['ecnum']?></textarea>
    <span class="ecfield"><?=$variable['field']?></span>
</li>
<?php }
```

?>

So, in theory, When they select an item, shouldn't it append to the `#select-result ul` unordered list, and add the `<li>` string? Anyone see why it wouldnt?

I have tested it, and I am receiving the correct data from the `.ui-selected` area and feeding numbers into the string.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the `selectable` class applied element?

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal added it in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#select-result').empty()` will remove all the elements inside the `#select-result` element. So `$("#select-result ul.ul-depend")` is not a valid selector. I have modified your code and it is working now.

add `steps` element to the markup,

```
<div id="select-result">
    <div class='steps'></div>
    <ul class='ul-depend'>Nothing Selected</ul>
</div>
```

and clear it instead,

```
$('#select-result .steps').empty().append(html2);
```

and clear `ul` as well,

```
$("#select-result ul.ul-depend").empty();
```

here is the working sample,
http://jsfiddle.net/FBY8y/

Comment: that was definitely it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're not appending anything to the ul, because you are removing it with the line

```
$('#select-result').empty().append(html2);
```